# Defining a "pass-through" style in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, styles, definition, custom-component

I have a custom component called `ButtonPanel` written in Actionscript.  Basically it's just a panel that displays a `mx:ButtonBar` in the upper right of the `mx:Panel` title bar and responds to the clicks of the buttons in the bar.

A ButtonBar has three styles available for the buttons:  `buttonStyleName`, `firstButtonStyleName`, and `lastButtonStyleName`.  I want to write these styles for the `ButtonPanel` so that if it is declared as such:

```
<comp:ButtonPanel buttonStyleName="myButtonStyle" ... />
```

then the `ButtonPanel` will pass the style through and set the corresponding style of the `ButtonBar`.

I really have no clue where to start on this because I've never messed with defining styles.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you refer to as "pass-through" styles are actually called inheriting styles. The solution to your question is in fact quite simple.

You use the [style metadata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf680e1-7ffe.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a1a) on your custom component to declare that ButtonPanel has a stylename called 'buttonStyleName':

```
[Style(name="buttonStyleName", inherit="yes")]

public class ButtonPanel extends Panel {
     ....
}
```

Note the 'inherit' flag which is set to true: this will make sure that any component inside your custom Panel that has the same style will inherit the value that you've given to that style at the Panel level.

Setting this metadata will make sure that FlashBuilder will suggest buttonStyleName as a style and not as a property (as would happen with Sam's solution).

---

**Edit**: already defined styles

I didn't realize at first that you were referring to the mx ButtonBar (as it's not explicitly mentioned). The reason this is not working for you is that mx:ButtonBar already has these styles defined as not inheriting. Look at the source code:

```
[Style(name="firstButtonStyleName", type="String", inherit="no")]
[Style(name="buttonStyleName", type="String", inherit="no")]
[Style(name="lastButtonStyleName", type="String", inherit="no")]
```

Because of this the compiler will complain when you try to override that definition in your custom Panel, because it simply wouldn't know which of the contradictory instructions to pick. So we'll have to do a little more work if you want to stick with mx:ButtonBar.

First define the styles on ButtonPanel exactly as they are defined in mx:ButtonBar so they have the same signature (you can just copy/paste the three lines above). This will shut up the compiler but the styles won't be inherited anymore, right?

So we'll have to pass them on manually: in your custom Panel skin, override the `updateDisplayList()` method and - assuming that the ButtonBar's id is 'buttonBar' - add the following:

```
    private const buttonStyles:Array = [
        "firstButtonStyleName",
        "buttonStyleName",
        "lastButtonStyleName"
    ];

    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, 
                                                  unscaledHeight:Number):void 
    {
        if (buttonBar) 
            for each (var buttonStyle:String in buttonStyles)
                buttonBar.setStyle(buttonStyle, getStyle(buttonStyle));

        //some other code

        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
    }
```

This will take the styles from the host Panel and pass them on to the ButtonBar.

Comment: OK, this makes sense.  I thought "inherit" meant for any subclasses of this class, but it means "children of me in the layout will inherit".  However, it does not seem to work.  `<comp:ButtonPanel buttonStyleName="myStyle" ... />`  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @istrasci Just saw I forgot to mention I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you do this in setStyle() or commitProperties() ? updateDisplayList() gets called more frequently than the first two.

Comment: @RichardHaven It's been a while since I've answered this, but I believe I tried `styleChanged`, which didn't work out too well (I believe it didn't get called on initialization). I do not think that ´commitProperties´ will be executed when a style is changed. As for `setStyle` that's up for testing...

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass these styles through, you only have to store them as string variables, and then pass them to the internal ButtonBar.

```
<mx:ButtonBar ... buttonStyleName="{buttonStyleName}" ... />

[Bindable]public var buttonStyleName:String;
```

If these two lines of code don't explain it fully to you, let me know and I can flesh out my example.